# Code works only in Visual Studio Debug but not in release mode nor .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've wrote an application to change the display resolution. (I'm used to play CS at 4:3 resolution and working at 16:9 and I'm too lazy to go to Systemcontrol and change it there.)

The program works fine as long as i run it with Visual Studio (Pro 2013) in Debug Mode, but if I change to Release Mode or try to run the .exe files it doesnt work.

Edit: I've got no errors and it looks like it does change the resolution (black monitor) but it does'nt change the resolution. Also tried to run wih admin rights.

Does anyone has an idea to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

struct SResolution
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

static SResolution R_1440x1080 = { 1440, 1080 };
static SResolution R_1920x1080 = { 1920, 1080 };

bool GetPrimaryDisplayDevice(DISPLAY_DEVICE& _rDisplayDevice);

int main()
{
    SResolution Resolution = R_1920x1080; // R_1440x1080 R_1920x1080

    DISPLAY_DEVICE  DDevice;
    DEVMODE         lpDevMode;
    DEVMODE         lpDevMode2;

    ZeroMemory(&DDevice   , sizeof(DDevice));
    ZeroMemory(&lpDevMode , sizeof(lpDevMode));
    ZeroMemory(&lpDevMode2, sizeof(lpDevMode2));

    DDevice.cb        = sizeof(DDevice);
    lpDevMode .dmSize = sizeof(lpDevMode);
    lpDevMode2.dmSize = sizeof(lpDevMode2);

    if (!GetPrimaryDisplayDevice(DDevice)) return 0;

    if (!EnumDisplaySettings(DDevice.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &lpDevMode)) return 0;

    // if (Resolution.x == lpDevMode.dmPelsWidth && Resolution.y == lpDevMode.dmPelsHeight) return 0;

    int i = 0;

    while (EnumDisplaySettings(DDevice.DeviceName, i, &lpDevMode))
    {
        if (Resolution.x == lpDevMode.dmPelsWidth && Resolution.y == lpDevMode.dmPelsHeight)
        {
            lpDevMode2 = lpDevMode;
        }

        i++;
    }

    lpDevMode2.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_POSITION | DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY | DM_DISPLAYFLAGS;

    DWORD Flags = CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_FULLSCREEN;

    if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&lpDevMode2, Flags) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Fail", (LPCWSTR)L"Error", MB_ICONHAND);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool GetPrimaryDisplayDevice(DISPLAY_DEVICE& _rDisplayDevice)
{
    DWORD           NumberOfDevice = 0;
    DWORD           dwFlags = 0;

    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, NumberOfDevice, &_rDisplayDevice, dwFlags))
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE InnerDDevice = { 0 };
        DWORD          InnerNumberOfDevice = 0;

        ZeroMemory(&InnerDDevice, sizeof(InnerDDevice));
        InnerDDevice.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

        if (_rDisplayDevice.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE)
        {
            return true;
        }

        NumberOfDevice++;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit2: **Solved.** - the problem was the CDS_FULLSCREEN flag at:

```
DWORD Flags = CDS_FULLSCREEN | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY;

ChangeDisplaySettings(&DMode, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY);
```

I've deleted this flag and only use CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY. Now it works.

Thanks to everyone who helped me or gave me tips :)

Comment: You have hit undefined behavior probably?

Comment: oh I've forgot to mention :X no. it looks like it does change the resolution but it does'nt. no failures

Comment: Are the settings same for the release and debug configurations?

Comment: @Chris I'm afraid we cannot tell with that narrow information given. You should note that in debug mode variables are initialized with certain value, while in release mode they aren't.

Comment: yes the settings are the same. I've just changed from debug to release mode.

Comment: add a ton of `printf` statements until you find something not normal. Could be a nice way of doing it: run the debug version and the release version and compare the output. Any difference reveals the source of the problem (unless it's memory allocations!)

Comment: Seriously: May the upvoter explain why this (seemingly unsalvable question) deserves an upvote please??

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ nice to mention this. but which of my variables isnt initialized?

Comment: @Chris As far I spot from your example, all of them are, that's what I meant when saying your question is _seemingly not salvable_ :(.

Comment: Tip 1: Instead of calling `ZeroMemory`, just zero-initialize the variables.

Comment: Tip 2: Instead of `return 0;` when something fails, which contrary to fact indicates success, return a failure indication such as `EXIT_FAILURE` from the `<stdlib.h>` header.

Comment: Tip 3: Instead of declaring a variable and using a `while` loop that increments that variable at the end, you can use a `for` loop.

Comment: Part of the problems: after the `while` loop there's no check if it found the resolution  you want.

Comment: Tip 4: The cast in `(LPCWSTR)L"Fail"` is Evil™. It only serves to hide a possible error, which is a pretty dumb thing to do. Don't do that.

Comment: Tip 5: `return 0;` at the end of `main` is not necessary. This is the default for `main`.

Comment: tip 1: how should i "zero-initialize" this? tip 3: till when do i count?. yep i forgot to check that. but the resolution exists and it actually change the resolution. the problem is the CDS_FULLSCREEN flag.

Comment: `DISPLAY_DEVICE  DDevice{};` or `DISPLAY_DEVICE  DDevice = {};`.

Comment: thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually does change the resolution. Add an else statement after this

```
if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&lpDevMode2, Flags) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Fail", (LPCWSTR)L"Error", MB_ICONHAND);
}
```

like this

```
else 
{
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Success", (LPCWSTR)L"Congrats", MB_ICONHAND);
}
```

And you will see that the resolution has changed but switched back when the program finished.

I wanted to post it as a comment since I don't know how to fix it, but I don't have enough reputation for commenting yet.

Comment: actually that helped a lot. i now know that the problem is the CDS_FULLSCREEN flag... but i need that one to stretch the resolution :X